# Task scheduler error

Tags: windows, task-scheduler

When I open task scheduler in windows 7 it gives an error saying:
 [image]

```
The selected task "{0}" no longer exists. To see the current tasks click refresh.
```

Then another error comes like this:
[image]
    Task scheduler service is not available.Task scheduler will attempt to reconnect to it.
Then task scheduler shows nothing like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you go into C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\ check if there is anything you do not recognise and maybe cut/paste all out to a backup folder to see if it fixes the issue. Normally a corrupt task in this folder causes issues like this.